# Debug Service Log On Credentials

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, services, debug, credentials

So I have a third party service that is failing to start due to "Logon Failure" as the Windows Event Viewer reports. I know the credentials I give it are correct, and when it fails, I can input those same credentials again and it will run fine for a while until a reboot. Sometimes reboot doesn't cause the issue, sometimes it does.

**The real question:** Is there any way to get Windows to report/log/dump the username/password that is trying to be used to authenticate the service? It's not something I've written, it's a third party service that's installed with a software suite.

Any help is much appreciated!

**[Update]**

I know PowerShell can be used to get the service's StartName, but is there any way to pull the password it's trying to use to authenticate with? I would venture a guess and say Windows wouldn't allow this because of various security concerns, but from a development standpoint it seems like a very useful debugging tool to be able to ensure the username/password the service is attempting to use is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question for anyone looking for similar information.

By using PsExec from sysinterals you can gather SYSTEM & SECURITY reg hives from the windows pc.

Running those through Cain&Abel you can easily decode and view plaintext passwords that the services are using.